# How to use custom fonts in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, css, handlebars.js

Hello guys I am quite stuck in getting custom fonts in my handlebars template.

So I am creating a statement template using handlebars and then I compile it in pdf before saving it. My problem now is that the fonts are never get while on server. If locally everything is fine.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I've tried with relative path and absolute path but the result is the same.

this is my statement.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
      @font-face {
        font-family: "lato-regular";
        src: url("./src/services/templates/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf")
          format("truetype");
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: "lato-light";
        src: url("./src/services/templates/fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf")
          format("truetype");
      }
      body {
        font-family: "lato-light";
        margin: 40px;
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
   ....
  </body
</html>
```

this is createStatement.js

```
const compile = async function(templateName, data) {
  const filePath = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    "src/services/templates",
    `${templateName}.html`
  );
  const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8");
  const templateScript = await hbs.compile(html);
  const res = templateScript(data);
  return res;
};

hbs.registerHelper("dateFormat", function(value, format) {
  return moment(value).format(format);
});

async function createStatement() {
  try {
    const content = await compile("statement", data);

    var options = { format: "A4" };

    pdf
      .create(content, options)
      .toFile("./src/services/template.pdf", function(err, res) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/mypdf.pdf' }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What component is `pdf`? And how does the pdf conversion convert the relative paths in `statement.html` into absolute paths? Ie. likely you pdf conversion cannot access the font files because the `src` paths are relative.

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, how?